# Get all users and order by the number of post in symfony

Tags: symfony, entity-relationship

I have two entity, User & Post.  These entities are connected with onetomany and manytoone relations.  The connections are working fine.  I've been trying to create a query that would get all users with post and order them by their number of post in descending order.

User Entity:

```
/**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Post", mappedBy="user")
     */
     private $post;
```

Post Entity:

```
/**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="post")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
     private $user;
```

There's no problem, basically, I just can't figure out how to make the query in symfony.

So, here's the basic query that returns all users

```
$query = $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
            ->leftJoin('u.post', 'p')
            ->getQuery();

        return $query->getResult();
```

Comment: Please show your query and tell us what problems you have with it.

Comment: Hi @dbrumann, the problem is am not quite sure how to create the doctrine query

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I can't reply as comments, I'm glad you got it sorted. But please consider the future, and scalability. It is not a good idea to count posts every time, or even once to be brutally honest. Consider doing what most forum softwares do now and when a post is made increment a field instead (call it post_count or something).

You can either decrement it on post deletion, or offer a 'recount' option where admins can force a recount but this should be a last resort.

Comment: You are right in that fetching all items to count them in php is not a good idea. Having an additional column for that, seems like another bad idea though. This field might get out of sync and is useless overhead anyway. MySQL can perform fast COUNT-queries over your data without the need of having additional "helper"-fields. You should either find a way to order by count with Doctrine ORM or create a custom repository where you write the query yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I seem to manage to sort his out.  Here is the query:

```
$query = $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
            ->select('u')
            ->leftJoin('u.post', 'p')
            ->addSelect('COUNT(p) AS total')
            ->groupBy('u.id')
            ->orderBy('total', 'DESC')
            ->getQuery();

        return $query->getResult();
```